# Value initialize aggregate

Tags: c++, value-initialization

Tried C++ standard, but couldn't figure it out. Are these equivalent?

```
double x[2] = {0.0, 0.0};
```

and

```
double x[2] = {};
```

How about these?

```
struct A {
    double x[2];
};

A a = {0.0, 0.0};
```

and

```
A a = {};
```

Thank you!

Comment: C or C++? You've tagged the question with both.

Comment: It's supposed to be `A a = { {0.0, 0.0} };`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ standard says (8.5.1):

> If there are fewer initializers in the
>   list than there are members in the
>   aggregate, then each member not
>   explicitly initialized shall be
>   value-initialized

and value-initialization of a double is to set it to `0.0`.

So yes!  In C++ they are equivalent.

[*I haven't had time to check the C99 standard.*]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are.

Compiler fills the initialization with zeroes when not enough given per declared size.